# Compare glDrawElements performance against expected GPU performance?

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering a very large mesh (heightmap) on an integrated Intel UHD 630 GPU, using OpenGL 4.5, and am trying to get some idea of whether the performance I'm getting is expected for this (admittedly lower level) GPU, or whether I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

The mesh is generated from a 1024x1024 image, resulting in in a single large mesh:

- Vertex buffer: 4190766 vertices (167630640 bytes)
- Index buffer: 6285870 indices (25143480 bytes)

I'm using a VBO with GL_STATIC_DRAW set, and the mesh is uploaded only once when the program starts. It is drawn with a single glDrawElements call.

Currently my frame time is 9ms. If I disable the glDrawElements call for the mesh (leaving only the other smaller meshes and UI drawing), my frame time drops well below 1ms. So almost all draw time is spent on this one large draw call.

However, I would have expected better performance, even on this GPU. The mesh is in a VBO, it already has the data, so I don't know why it is taking 9ms to draw.

Is there a way of knowing what this GPU is actually capable of, and whether this frame time is to be expected when drawing 4mil+ vertices?

Comment: "*However, I would have expected better performance, even on this GPU.*" Why? You appear to be shoving ~2 million triangles. At 10ms per frame, that's ~200 million triangles per second. That's very respectable for an integrated GPU.

Comment: _"That's very respectable for an integrated GPU"_ That is what I was hoping to get answered, as I don't know what an integrated GPU should be capable of these days. Modern games shove massive numbers of triangles, and I'm close to the frame limit with a single (albeit large) draw call. I wanted to learn what that limit should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU is having to render more than 2 million triangles per frame, which is a lot to ask from an integrated card that came out more than 4 years ago.

If you're looking into optimizing performance then I would suggest the following:

Instead of generating a vertex for every heightmap pixel, generate a more sparse uniform grid of vertices (lets say, one world unit apart) and elevate them according to their respective heightmap value. If you require more precision in certain areas where the height values vary a lot, you could tessellate those specific areas while keeping flat ones with lower vertex density. You could take it further and collapse triangles that lay on flat surfaces and thus not offer much in terms of terrain detail, this should significantly reduce your vertex count depending on the heightmaps you're using.

Another method that should offer a very significant boost in terms of framerate would be to break up your large mesh into smaller ones and implement various culling methods that ensure only those terrain pieces which are visible to the camera are rendered. The most important of these would be frustum culling, which would spare your GPU from having to process hundreds of thousands of vertices which would never be visible anyway. A good resource on frustum culling that personally helped me a lot and was very easy to implement can be found [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/geometric-approach-testing-boxes-ii/).